# How to pull data from child installation to parent theme

Tags: multisite

I want to build a very large application, where I want to give some parts a whole new look, for example my site consists of Blog, Shop, Activities, calendar, and lots of different sections

I want to give admin rights to some of the guys so they can post data, but I also want to keep my site same across all the sections, 
I want to pull data from Blog or Activities / Events section, and display them on my home page, and I also want all of the sections and home page to have same header footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enable [WPMU](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and make custom functions to get/post data from one blog to another (using [switch_to_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)). WPMU installs different tables for each blog you create on one WP installation.

If you want to have the same design, child theme can be enabled on one WP installation. You cannot switch between child and parent theme just to get different data. You should clear things up.

**Example:** *(not complete - i use more to do my work)*

```
function copy_data_to_other_site($post_id)
{
    $current_user = get_current_user_id(); // get user id

    $target_blog_id = get_user_meta($current_user, 'primary_blog', true); // get blog id by user

        $post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A); // get the original post

        $the_slug = $post['name'];

        switch_to_blog($target_blog_id); // switch to target blog

        $args = array(
            'name' => $the_slug,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => 1
        );

        $my_posts = get_posts($args);

        $target_car = wp_insert_post($my_posts); // insert the post

        restore_current_blog(); // return to original blog
}
```

Comment: can you give any example?

Comment: Check update of my answer